# Why NbAdjustableConnectedPositionStrategy error and how solve this pain

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, nebular

Here is my template and I used nebular theme for UI[image]

In the previous project, I did not get this error. But in this project Nx(monorepo), I got this error.
When I click to name of , popover pane is showing wrong position and I got this error[image]

[image]

I tried my best, but I am not still OK for this issue. Please help and advice me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I updated to the most recent version of Nebular.
You might have to update `@angular/cdk`also that has a minimal version of `10.2.2`

my `package.json`

```js
"@nebular/auth": "6.2.1",
"@nebular/firebase-auth": "^6.2.1",
"@nebular/eva-icons": "6.2.1",
"@nebular/security": "6.2.1",
"@nebular/theme": "6.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and ended up solving it by removing the `NbLayoutScrollService` from various `providers: []` arrays in modules throughout the app.